# Idomatic way to ignore `finally` block after cancelling network request

Tags: javascript, react.js, axios

In React, it is quite common for me to have something similar to the following.

```
async componentDidMount() {
    try {
        this.setState({ isLoading: true })
        const { data } = await axios.get('...')
        this.setState({ data })
    } catch(error) {
         handleError(error)
    } finally {
        this.setState({ isLoading: false })
    }
}
```

This is great because the cleanup code (`isLoading: false`) is DRY. That is, until I try to cancel network requests on unmount. That code would look like this:

```
async componentDidMount() {
    try {
        this.axiosCancelTokenSource = axios.CancelToken.source()
        this.setState({ isLoading: true })
        const { data } = await axios.get('...', {
            cancelToken: this.axiosCancelTokenSource.token,
        })
        this.setState({ data })
    } catch(error) {
         if (axios.isCancel(error)) return
         handleError(error)
    } finally {
        this.setState({ isLoading: false })
    }
}
componentWillUnmount() {
    if (this.axiosCancelTokenSource) this.axiosCancelTokenSource.cancel()
}
```

The problem with this is that it will `setState` after the component unmounts, which React will warn againts.

As far as I see it, these are my options for dealing with this:

1. Ignore the warning.
   React gives a warning when you `setState` after unmount because it indicates a memory leak (in this case, the lingering network request, if not cancelled). If the network request is cancelled, there is still a `setState` after unmount, but just to set a flag. There is no more lingering network request. It should be safe to ignore the warning in this case, but it doesn't feel right.
2. Check what error was thrown in the `finally` block and add the same `if` statement as the `catch` block. This seems incredibly hacky and would require extra code to save the error from the catch block.
3. Check if the component is mounted in the `finally` block. This is also hacky and requires boilerplate code to update a `this.isMounted` flag.
4. Put the cleanup code at the end of `try` and after the condition in `catch`. This is not DRY. Humans are also very forgetful; I cannot count how many times I have forgotten to set `isLoading = false` in catch.
5. Define a `cleanup()` function before the `try` and call it in `try` and `catch`. This is a decent option, but requires extra function calls, making it harder to follow.

So far, it looks like the first or fifth options are best, depending on how much you care about seeing warning messages. Am I missing any good options?

Comment: IMHO 5th option but that's just personal opinion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Finally only for unconditional execution

I am not a React user, and as such I may be missing something unique to the React way.

It seams very strange that you use a `finally` block to execute code you don't want to guarantee execution.

> As far as I see it, these are my options for dealing with this:

You list 5 options... Why not a 6th?

6. Remove the `finally { ... }` block setting the is loading state after the `try catch` and having the catch return if unmounted.

If I ignore React the *"Idomatic way to ignore `finally` block..."* is to remove it.

eg

```
async componentDidMount() {
    try {
        this.axiosCancelTokenSource = axios.CancelToken.source()
        this.setState({ isLoading: true })
        const { data } = await axios.get('...', {
            cancelToken: this.axiosCancelTokenSource.token,
        })
        this.setState({ data })
    } catch(error) {
         if (axios.isCancel(error)) return
         handleError(error)
    }
    this.setState({ isLoading: false })
}
```

#### Catch only known exceptions

`try ... catch` should only be used to wrap code that is known to throw a known set of exceptions (in this case network, data, or forced exceptions related to `axios.get`).

Wrapping all code automatically in a `try catch` means that it is possible to catch unknown exceptions (AKA BUGS) effectively hiding/obscuring the erroneous behavior during the development cycle.

#### Example

Removing the `try` from around known safe code, catching only exceptions related to the functions role.

```
// pseudo code as example only
async mount() {
    loading = (isLoading = true) => this.setState({isLoading});
    cancelToken = axios.CancelToken.source();
    loading();
    try {
        this.setState({data: (await axios.get("...", {cancelToken})).data});
    } catch (e) {
         if (axios.isCancel(e)) { return }
         handleError(e);
    } 
    loading(false);
}
```

Comment: Can't believe I didn't think of this.

Comment: This bothered me for quite awhile now and only did a research. Thanks for this!

Answer (score 4):

> Ignore the warning. React gives a warning when you setState after
>   unmount because it indicates a memory leak (in this case, the
>   lingering network request, if not canceled). If the network request
>   is canceled, there is still a setState after unmount, but just to set
>   a flag. There is no more lingering network request. It should be safe
>   to ignore the warning in this case, but it doesn't feel right.

Bad idea. Thing is, by the time the request will resolve, setState might be triggered on an unmounted component. And warning turns to error.

> Check what error was thrown in the finally block and add the same if
>   statement as the catch block. This seems incredibly hacky and would
>   require extra code to save the error from the catch block.

Meh :\

> Check if the component is mounted in the finally block. This is also
>   hacky and requires boilerplate code to update a this.isMounted flag.

[It's an Anti-pattern](https://reactjs.org/blog/2015/12/16/ismounted-antipattern.html)

[image]

> Put the cleanup code at the end of try and after the condition in
>   catch. This is not DRY. Humans are also very forgetful; I cannot count
>   how many times I have forgotten to set isLoading = false in catch.

This

> Define a cleanup() function before the try and call it in try and
>   catch. This is a decent option, but requires extra function calls,
>   making it harder to follow.

And that, are pretty much taking the same turn with different gear.

**Suggestion from [React Blog](https://reactjs.org/blog/2015/12/16/ismounted-antipattern.html)**

If you use ES6 promises, you may need to wrap your promise in order to make it cancelable.

```
const cancelablePromise = makeCancelable(
  new Promise(r => component.setState({...}))
);

cancelablePromise
  .promise
  .then(() => console.log('resolved'))
  .catch((reason) => console.log('isCanceled', reason.isCanceled));

cancelablePromise.cancel(); // Cancel the promise
```

Where makeCancelable was originally defined by @istarkov as:

```
const makeCancelable = (promise) => {
  let hasCanceled_ = false;

  const wrappedPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    promise.then(
      val => hasCanceled_ ? reject({isCanceled: true}) : resolve(val),
      error => hasCanceled_ ? reject({isCanceled: true}) : reject(error)
    );
  });

  return {
    promise: wrappedPromise,
    cancel() {
      hasCanceled_ = true;
    },
  };
};
```

Comment: Your answer might be better if you provided at least a small part of the anti-pattern link in your own words around the line.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Under what circumstances will the "setState in unmounted component" throw an error not a warning? You say it's when the component is not mounted, but that's the whole point of the warning. I fail to see when it becomes an error. Also, where's the shame in considering an anti-pattern and deciding against it?

Answer (score 2):

If you have some problems with the other answers, you can immediately stop loading if it is not cancelling:

```
async mount() {
    loading = (isLoading = true) => this.setState({isLoading});
    cancelToken = axios.CancelToken.source();
    loading();
    try {
        this.setState({data: (await axios.get("...", {cancelToken})).data});
    } catch (e) {
         if (!axios.isCancel(e)) { loading(false); }
         handleError(e);
    } 
}
```